# Many tables for api restful Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a question about architecture of my project.
I need to create 10 apis rest, but my database has 300 tables around without relationship.

My question is: It's necessary create all entities from my database?
What is the best practice? Generator Hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It's necessary create all entities from my database?

It's NOT necessary to generate **all** entities. For your use case, filter out the tables which are going to be in use by 10 rest APIs and create entities only for these tables. The list may include 5, 10 or 30 tables (count doesn't matter). To be more precise, you only need to create entities against tables on which you intend to work directly or indirectly for these endpoints.

> What is the best practice? Generator Hibernate?

Almost always, entities generated by hibernate generator are good start but most often than not, generated entities are far from perfect (or near perfect). As an example, a joiner table in db usually end up being a separate Entity. Feel free to use hibernate entity generator for tables you need (yes, you can specify handful tables using "Table Filters") but I'll strongly advise to revisit all generated entities and tune them as per your specific needs. I personally prefer to hand-code entities myself instead of using generator, especially if the entities are handful.

With regard to best modeling techniques, that's a vast topic and I'll suggest to ***start*** with hibernate official documentation. While the documentation focus on hibernate specifics, it talks about various modeling techniques in hibernate feature context and which one is suited for which purpose. You may also want to look at JPA tutorials OR even spring-data-jpa for that matter.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Friend, you're awesome. Thank u for u answer. It's perfectly to me.